# How to save status for every TCP stream in Wireshark with Lua

Tags: lua, wireshark

I am trying to write a dissector to dissect my protocol in Wireshark. There are some statuses I want to save for every TCP stream (or session). I want to know the last packet length in the same TCP stream.

I try to use a big table to store. I use the IP and port to index the stream but it has an amazing bug. When I double-click the Pinfo columns, the result in the tree item (which had dissected correctly) goes bad suddenly.

So, can someone help me? I was not native speaker, so sorry for my bad descriptions.

Answer (score 0):

This was answered on [ask.wireshark.org](https://ask.wireshark.org/questions/42711/lua-dissector-puzzle-how-to-save-state).